# jQuery kill link if li has children

Tags: jquery

Given the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="example.com>1</a></li>
    <li><a href="example.com>2</a></li>
    <li><a href="example.com>3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="example.com">3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="example.com">3.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="example.com">3.2.1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="example.com>4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to auto remove or kill the link for `3` and `3.2`

Basically any li that has children the link should be removed.
What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to keep the text:

```
$('li:has(ul) > a').remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BqYL/)

If you want to keep the text, you could use [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$('li:has(ul) > a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BqYL/1/)

Comment: I new there would be something cool like that just couldn't think of it myself but what if he wants to keep the text in the link ?

Comment: @kylex: You might consider replacing it with another DOM element instead of their context only, so that you can wrap them into links again more easily. But that depends on your use case. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if I didn't tested, this should work:

```
$('li').filter(function(){ return $('ul', this).length ? this : ''; }).find('a:first').unwrap('<a></a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    if( $(this).parent().children('ul').length > 0 ){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the link from being followed
        $(this).remove(); //remove the a element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li > ul').parent().children("a").attr("href","#")
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery,

```
$('li > a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).siblings().length)
    $(this).remove();
});
```